# Problème In CRM DYNAMICS 365

Tags: c#, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am doing an automation test for the login To CRM DYNAMICS 365 ms when I would like to recover the input connect I had a problem  ( OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document       (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.163))

the login page is divided into 2 pages one for email and input with following value
the 2 page with iput password and input with value connect
so when i would like to locate the 2nd input with the value connect i had the problemme and a remark the 2 input in the same Id

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xikOu.png)

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Can you post the code, specifically the section of code, where this error is popping up?